# How to import a javascript file in Visualforce Markup?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

How to import a file in Visualforce Markup? I'm trying to reference a static resource in Salesforce with the URLFOR Function.

The following script works

```
<apex:page>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<p>Click Date to display current day, date, and time.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Date</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>

</body>
</html> 
</apex:page>
```

But, I'd like to implement the following by referencing the function within VisualForce

```
  <apex:page>
  <html>
  <body>
<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<p>Click Date to display current day, date, and time.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Date</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SalesDashboard, '/js/datefunction.js')}"/>

</body>
</html> 
</apex:page>
```

I've also tried:

```
      <apex:page>
      <html>
      <body>
    <h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

    <p>Click Date to display current day, date, and time.</p>

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Date</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>


   <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.SalesDashboard}"/>

    </body>
    </html> 
    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this salesforce link](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_javascript_intro.htm)

The best method for including JavaScript in a Visualforce page is placing the JavaScript in a static resource, then calling it from there. For example,

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.SalesDashboard}"/>
```

Comment: The issue is that I need to reference a file within an archive (see here: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources_reference.htm). Your suggestion only works when I added the static resource by itself, but I'm adding the static resource as azipped file

Comment: Chris, use the URLFOR function to get into the insides of the zip file: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources_reference.htm Or if you feel adventurous you can get inside directly, read the answer to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45387/accessing-local-static-resources-from-a-managed-package